# Angular.js format json data

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

```
"[{rest_id:"2", cate_id:"4", rest_name:"Samraat Curry Hut", adress:"6275 Jarvis Ave, Newark, CA 94560", city:"Newark", state:"New Jersey", country:"US", email_id:"", rest_url:"Samraat-Curry-Hut", phone_no:"(510) 745-7000", rest_image:"http://www.mealhi5.com/images/restaurant/Samraat-Curry-Hut.jpg"}]"
```

top array my result but my required bottom array add double quote key
rest_id to "rest_id" all key add double quote("")
my required array

This Angular JS
first JSON is my input and output second array

```
[{"rest_id":"2", "cate_id":"4", "rest_name":"Samraat Curry Hut", "adress":"6275 Jarvis Ave, Newark, CA 94560", "city":"Newark", "state":"New Jersey", "country":"US", "email_id":"", "rest_url":"Samraat-Curry-Hut", "phone_no":"(510) 745-7000", "rest_image":"http://www.mealhi5.com/images/restaurant/Samraat-Curry-Hut.jpg"}]
```

Comment: What's the question ?

Comment: `JSON.parse(yourString);`

Comment: Check my answer it will help you.

Comment: What is input and what is output you required ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/JSON/parse) (if you want to use it as a JSON object)

```
var foo = JSON.parse("[{rest_id:"2", ...}]");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing use regular expressing in that case:-

```
var a= JSON.stringify([{"rest_id":"2", "cate_id":"4", "rest_name":"Samraat Curry Hut", "adress":"6275 Jarvis Ave, Newark, CA 94560", "city":"Newark", "state":"New Jersey", "country":"US", "email_id":"", "rest_url":"Samraat-Curry-Hut", "phone_no":"(510) 745-7000", "rest_image":"http://www.mealhi5.com/images/restaurant/Samraat-Curry-Hut.jpg"}]);

a=a.replace(/"(\w+)"\s*:/g, '$1:');
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wdk7pa6y/)

Comment: @SirajuddinLuck can you please elaborate your problem ?

Comment: alert answer rest_id but my required "rest_id"

Comment: So you mean first JSON is your input and output you required is the second one ?

Comment: @SirajuddinLuck hey how it can be possible to encapsulate "(double quote) inside "(double quote) i mean your "[{rest_id:"2", is invalidated. Becuase start " end  " then 2 as a number and again start ". I guess there must be single quote ' encapsulate the whole JSON